# IP Filter for Azure Functions to only allow traffic from Azure API Management Service

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

My API has users upload and download files from Azure Storage containers. I have an API that uses two Azure Functions - one for uploading files, and one for generating SAS tokens. I want to secure the API and its Azure Functions by making the Azure Functions only accept traffic from the APIM's IP address. Each time I do this, however, any access to the Azure Functions are blocked. I added the APIM Virtual IP address to the allowed sources for each Azure Function under "Access Restrictions", but each time I try to access either of the functions I am met with a 403 (Ip Forbidden) error. What should I do?

**Edit:**
I've figured out that my HTML frontend is the reason why access is blocked: requests are sent through the HTML frontend, where they use the client's IP address.

Comment: Are you using a consumption plan or a dedicated plan? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-ip-addresses

Comment: I am using a Developer plan in APIM. I am not using a VNet either, as my Azure Functions are Consumption Tier.

Comment: What do you mean by "requests are sent via the HTML frontend, where they use the client's IP address"? Your function should block your browser but allow anything from your APIM. Your browser is calling your APIM, right?

Comment: If you are adding the APIM IP to the access restriction, only APIM would be able to access the functions. You cannot access them from your desktop or your html page or anywhere else unless you route your requests via APIM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that by "HTML frontend", you mean your client application running in a browser.

The Azure Function is seeing the client IP Address rather than the IP Address of the APIM.

The first thing to check is: Do the url's that you are using in the frontend go to APIM? Or do they go directly to the Azure Function.